# Ubuntu 21.04 165hz display stuck at 40hz

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

I'm trying to switch to Ubuntu on my laptop which has an RTX 3070 and Intel UHD graphics for 10th gen which I think they call GT2 graphics(?).

Ideally I want to use KDE as it's what I'm used to so I've installed Kubuntu.
However, I've got the NVidia proprietary drivers installed and my laptop seems to be stuck at a 40hz refresh rate. The displays configuration lets me choose 165hz but it doesn't seem to change anything, I've tried changing it in xrandr too but it hasn't done anything.

I've tried booting live USBs for POP_OS! and Manjaro linux too, and I still cannot change to 165 on those.

Any help getting this to work would be massively appreciated!

Comment: I've tried booting live USBs for POP_OS! and Manjaro linux too, and I still cannot change to 165 on those. This information does not help the question as this is a Ubuntu site.

Comment: I was hoping that saying all the things I've tried so far could help suggest what the problem may be :) Although POP_OS! is very very close to ubuntu anyway.

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the exact same problem with RTX 3070.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about i915 driver. It reads EDID file wrong. Here is the solution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680356/i915-driver-stuck-at-40hz-on-165hz-screen

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Supported intel gpus, generation 11 above ... according to this link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/747008/intel-arc-graphics-driver-ubuntu.html

Maybe the driver can be backported ...

I followed this above link steps instructions and no need to edit edid.bin. I think this dirvers are more updated. Works on my ubuntu 22.04

The essential steps i did are:

a) sudo apt-get install -y gpg-agent wget

b) wget -qO - https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/intel-graphics.key |sudo gpg --dearmor --output /usr/share/keyrings/intel-graphics.gpg

c) echo 'deb [arch=amd64,i386 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/intel-graphics.gpg] https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu jammy arc' |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel.gpu.jammy.list

d) sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y linux-image-5.17.0-1019-oem

e) sudo reboot

f) sudo apt-get -y install gawk dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) libc6-dev udev

g) sudo apt-get install -y intel-platform-vsec-dkms intel-platform-cse-dkms sudo apt-get install -y intel-i915-dkms intel-fw-gpu

h) [optional] sudo apt-get install -y
intel-opencl-icd intel-level-zero-gpu level-zero
intel-media-va-driver-non-free libmfx1 libmfxgen1 libvpl2
libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev libglx-mesa0 libigdgmm12 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers
mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers va-driver-all

i) sudo reboot

That's it it

Reference: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-jammy-arc.html#pre-installation-setting

Thank you