# GU603HM: Setting 165hz in desktop Linux distro looks like 60hz

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution, hybrid

**The Specs of The Laptop:**

- Intel® Core™ i7-11800H CPU
- 16GB Ram
- Nvidia RTX 3060 Laptop GPU

**Distros tested**:

- Ubuntu 21.10 (GNOME)
- Ubuntu 21.04 (GNOME)
- ArchLinux (GNOME,KDE)
- Garuda Linux (GNOME,KDE)
- Fedora 34 (GNOME)
- Deepin

**Issue:**
Whatever refresh rate you set in control panel, it will look like 60hz (Lagging, shadowing, etc.)
Even xrandr shows that 2560x1600@165hz is active option, but it doesn't look like 165hz whatever.

**Steps to reproduce:**
Boot any distro with Live CD (or fresh install), then set refresh rate in corresponding settings
Since it happens on every distro I've used, I'm suspecting that it's an OEM problem, not a distro problem.
In this laptop ASUS has introduced a refresh rate auto-switch via ArmouryCrate, so maybe it's something with RefreshRateService? (In other words, you need a specific ACPI call to activate real 165hz on this panel)
I'll post it here for further discussion.

**Here are some info:**

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 215mm
   2560x1600    165.04*+  60.03 +  59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     85.00    75.00    60.00  
   1920x1440     85.00    75.00    60.00  
   1856x1392     75.00    60.01  
   1792x1344     75.00    60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/As*
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/AsusEDID-607005d5-3f75-4b2e-98f0-85ba66797a3e  
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/AsusGpnvVersion-607005d5-3f75-4b2e-98f0-85ba66797a3e  
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/AsusManufactureVersion-607005d5-3f75-4b2e-98f0-85ba66797a3e  
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/AsusPanelODVar-e5973dfb-befa-dcba-8e62-ceaa684726dd  
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/AsusPostLogoSound-607005d5-3f75-4b2e-98f0-85ba66797a3e  
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/AsusVariable-607005d5-3f75-4b2e-98f0-85ba66797a3e
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure **seemed** to work for me (as noted by eminfedar at [Ubuntu 21.04 165hz display stuck at 40hz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366558/ubuntu-21-04-165hz-display-stuck-at-40hz)):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680356/i915-driver-stuck-at-40hz-on-165hz-screen

One quirky thing I noticed with the edid editing program (run through wine) was that changes made to edid.bin did not save properly... I had to save as a new file so that the pixel rate and refresh rate would be properly recorded.

However, as noted by 吴胜杰, the above solution appears to only work for a short while before becoming unstable and falling to lower refresh rates. Additionally, I noticed some graphical glitches accompanying this reduced refresh rate. Trying to figure out what might be going on, I'll update here if I figure anything out.

Update (01/14/22 12:47pm): Currently trying it out at a lower rate (120Hz).

Update (01/14/22 1:57pm): It seems that one issue might actually be with the UFO test website in firefox.  I was skeptical of its results, since it seemed that my panel was still operating at a higher rate than what the site was indicating (simply from visual inspection). I checked the same site on chrome, and it reported my refresh rate as 120Hz.

Update (01/18/2023 6:23pm): Freshly installing ubuntu 23.10.1 appears to completely resolve this problem without the need for editing edid files.

Comment: I followed the steps and it works for me. But the refresh rate is not stable, it changes between 165Hz and 70Hz(test through ufo test website), and most of time, the refresh rate is 70Hz. Do you konw how to solve the problem?

Comment: I noticed the same thing after further usage today. I've modified the answer to take note of this, and I'll update if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and encountered this problem as you described.This problem is due to the Intel Graphics(i915) not updated. I simply update it following this tutorial:https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-jammy-arc.html  , and then the problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thanks for adding this answer, but could you please also include the basic steps from the link you posted? Links are of no use if for some reason they stop working. Thanks!